# Saving in the destructor - bad idea?

Tags: php, orm, destructor

In a PHP app, would it be a bad idea to run my saving code during an object's destructor? I ask because if it's ok then I could add a `save()` call in the destructor of the parent Model class and save myself the trouble of remembering anywhere else.

I know that doing this does work, as I have an entire app (albeit a poorly written one) running on it. But are there good reasons not to do it?

Comment: how do you know a save is appropriate in a destructor? Perhaps the user pressed cancel.....

Comment: @MitchWheat Since it's a web app the object only lives for the life of the one request. So there's no possibility of cancelling during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor is not guaranteed to be called in any order. What happens if your page is unloading and all the objects instructors start to get called. you never know if the database object you need to use is still valid, or if it has been unloaded.

Comment: The DB object being destroyed is the kicker.

Comment: PHP only calls the `__destruct` function on objects with no references.  So if you have a reference to a DB object, it won't be destroyed before you get chance to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, PHP will try to destroy objects in the right order, so it is quite safe (considering if you're trying to save something, it means you are still hodling a reference to it). What you need to be aware of is that throwing an exception during a destructor will cause a fatal error even if there's a catch. You can play with examples, and it's not easy to make PHP fail with normal referencing, here's a simple way to make PHP crazy with destructors so it doesn't know how to end them, but as I said, it's not something you normally find in your code:

```
<?php
class A
{
    public $b;
    function eco()
    {
        echo 'AAA';
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $b->eco();
    }
}
class B
{
    public $a;
    function eco()
    {
        echo 'BBB';
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        $a->eco();
    }
}
$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$a->b = $b;
$b->a = $a;
```

Comment: When I change the last line to `$b->a = $b;`, PHP still tries to deconstruct `$a` first.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, adding such functionality into the destructor is not the best choice. The reason, one very important to me, is increased code complexity and reduced readability. A third person new to the project will end-up spending quite a bit of time figuring out whats been happening.

Having said that, whether it is theoretically good or bad, its down to the programming logic being employed. If the class in question would be extended at a latter stage, then the save() in your destructor might give you some grief; again depends on what you are trying to achieve.